Do dragonflies smell nice?
We found this dragonfly husk in a box of files and grates. People don't rummage around there too often but its undamaged condition two or three weeks after we saw it alive is still remarkable. There's just that hole on the back just behind the head with the torso's hollow below it. It is about 10 cm long.
While picking off some motes, holding the tail with two fingers, I noticed the husk smells sweet, really just like musk. Though of two colleagues only one perceived the same, the other said it was just musTy.
Now I wonder, is it just an agreeable sort of decay going on, or do dead dragonflies usually smell like that? Do live ones?



Feel free to add any appropriate tags. Thanks.

Welcome Ariola. I doubt that anyone will have looked and documented this for us to know. Having said that the Victorian passion for collecting and cataloguing might have turned up something, but only an expert who has read species descriptions would note something like that in the literature. I'd suspect that there are other possible causes: bacterial/fungal decay smell, something else in the tool box like an oil or wood shavings, or possibly something like a mouse has passed through and left some urine/droppings.
